# autolayout view gets overlapped on smaller devices

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, aspect-ratio, autoresizingmask

Basically I have one view with some height x
and 4 other views with same height y all these 5 views are vertically one after another with 10 px space

all these views have again some child views which depends on them.

For this scenario stackview is ideal but it support starts from iOS 9 unfortunately I have to support from iOS 6

so basically I fixed all the views with leading,trailing,top,bottom and height constraint...

it works good in iPhone 7s ... but in iphone 4s the view gets overlapped on each other

in iphone se the views are very much congested..

I was always thinking the height will change according to the screen size for iPHone 4s but that didn't happen

How can I work this out ?

Comment: Why would you think that the height would change if you have configured fixed height?  I realise it may be out of your control, but ios9+ is 95% of devices;  I would think that the number of devices running < iOS 8 is a fraction of a percent

Comment: @Paulw11 - but according to the project spec I have to support :(

Comment: If I remove the heght constraint can I achieve  withouyt any UI problem.. If u were given this to be done what constraints u would have used .... can u explain me step by step please

Comment: If you can't use stack layout then you will either need to use an aspect ratio constraint to set the height of your first item relative to the screen height and then use 'equal height' constraints between the other items and the first item or modify your constraints at runtime when the screen height is known

Comment: @Paulw11 - how do I use an aspect ratio constraint to set the height of your first item relative to the screen height ? If you could explain me a bit with screenshot I'd be really grateful to you

Comment: first view is having one height and rest of the other views are having different height .. so giving equal height to all the siblings would be a bad idea I think .. How do I place this without overlapping other views ? P.S each of these views again have some views inside vertically one after another

Comment: I think the simplest approach will be for you to set your height constraints programatically in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: You mean to say I have to manually calculate all the frames and update it according to the device  ?

Comment: Yes, but don't change the frames; set the `constant` on your height constraints so that auto layout still works for everything else.

Comment: Thanks,So one more doubt , how bout size classes would that be a good option in the scenario ?

Comment: I don't think that size classes will give you the degree of flexibility you are after

Comment: @Paulw11 why would you want to set your height constraint in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and not `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Because they will want to calculate the constraint height based on the frame height and the frame height won't be set until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - before that point you will get 1000 x 1000 for the root view frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem you are facing.

**First:**

Instead of giving a fixed height to any of your `UIView` you can use a proportional height constraint. Select your `UIView` and <kbd>control</kbd> + drag from your `UIView` to the main superview. Select equal height constraint. Now, double click the height constraint and set the multiplier to 0.15 or any value you seem nice. This will ensure the view thus created is always 0.15 times the entire view's height. Now you can create your other views either proportional to this view following the same steps or to the superview.

[image]

**Second:**
(I prefer this approach as for items as sometimes you need to create forms the above approach might still push elements off the screen).

This will use a `UIScrollView`. To your main view add a `UIScrollView` and add a *leading*, *trailing*, *top* and *bottom* constraint to your *superview*. Add a `UIView` to this `UIScrollView` and give it a *leading*, *trailing*, *top* and *bottom* as well. Additionally give it a *equal height* and *width* constraints to the superview of the `UIScrollView` with a low priority of like say 250. Now add all your elements inside this `UIView` however you seem fit. With fixed height, proportional height whatever and happily run it. But ensure you add a bottom of `>=` a minimum value for your bottom most view.

The screen will automatically become scrollable if the content will go off screen otherwise it won't be scrollable at all.

Answer (score 0):

fixed all the views with leading,trailing,top,bottom and equal height  constraint instead of only height(not give fixed height to any view)

[image]

Comment: How do I set equal height constraint ? Can you attach a screenshot or give me steps ? I am newbie to this stuff

Comment: Thanks.My first view is having one height and rest of the other views are having different height .. so giving equal height to all the siblings would be a bad idea I think ..  How do I place this without overlapping other views ? P.S each of these views again have some views inside vertically one after another